# JAVA MAIL API : Unable to attach xls file to Mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, attachment

My below Java class has to copy a text file content and mail to recipients, along with a attached xls file,using java mail.

Now I can read and Mail the text file content but unable to attach the xls file.

Below are my snippet:

```
static void sendmail() throws IOException,     
MessagingException,AddressException,FileNotFoundException
   {

          DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 
HH:mm:ss");
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String to1=getOrderinfo.to1;
            String to2 = getOrderinfo.to2;
            String to3 = getOrderinfo.to3; 
            String to4 = getOrderinfo.to4;
            String from =getOrderinfo.from;
            String host = getOrderinfo.host;
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
             Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();



            String pathLogFile = "E:/car_failed_report/log.txt";

            try {

                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
InternetAddress(to1));
                   message.setSubject(" CAR NOT YET INTEGRATED REPORT at 
: "+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    FileInputStream fstream = new 
FileInputStream(pathLogFile);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(fstream));

                    String singleLine;
                    while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    {

                        sb.append(singleLine + "<br>");
                       // CarParser1.sb1.append(singleLine +"<br>");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    String allLines;

                   allLines = sb.toString();


                    String allLines_html=" <html><head><title></title> 
</head>"
                            + "<body >"+allLines+"</body ></html>";
                  message.setContent(allLines_html, "text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1");

                 MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                File attachement = new File("E:\\car_failed_report
\\failed.xls");
                if (attachement.exists()) {
                    attachPart.attachFile(attachement);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR READING THE FILE");
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();
                }

                 Transport.send(message);



                System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");


                System.out.println();

            } 
            catch(FileNotFoundException f1)
            {
                System.out.println("File not yet created..this is from 
mailer class");

                return;
            }
            catch (MessagingException mex) 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Email Address.please provide 
a valid email id to send with");
                mex.printStackTrace();


            }
```

Can any one Help me to attach the xls file.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry but if you alread know the problem, fix it... I'm out. Attach a file is not reading it even printing it and either set as body content... But if you don't care about our advices I cannot help.

Comment: Grab idea from this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-with-attachment/ and check if you can send the xls file.

Comment: @ jordi:Thank you for your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the body part with the attachment but didn't add it to the message.  Replace your code starting with message.setContent:

```
            MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
            body.setText(allLines_html, "iso-8859-1", "html");
            mp.addBodyPart(body);

            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            File attachement = new File("E:\\car_failed_report\\failed.xls");
            if (attachement.exists()) {
                attachPart.attachFile(attachement);
                mp.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR READING THE FILE");
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            message.setContent(mp);
```